# Is it possible to make the operating system itself use less RAM?

Tags: windows, memory

In the same system with Windows installed, if I insert only 2GB RAM card in the motherboard, Windows uses about 500MB right after boot, but if I install 16GB of RAM in the motherboard and reboot, Windows is using 3-4GB right after boot even though I didn't open any programs. This is annoying since Windows itself is trying to use af much RAM as possible. Is it possible to use 16GB RAM on my computer but make Windows use only about 500MB of RAM right after boot? or make the system think there is little RAM so Windows will try to save RAM as much as possible but actually all other programs can use all my 16GB RAM?

Don't say to limit the RAM capacity in msconfig.exe because that will limit the total RAM that Windows and other programs can use.

Comment: *Unused RAM is dead RAM*. There were already so many questions like this on superuser, and this isn't the 90s anymore. The more RAM being used the better. They're used for caches and things like that, and will be returned to any program in need

Comment: Only using 500MB of RAM means it likely has the rest paged out to the swap file, losing performance, wasting write cycles (on SSD) and using more disk space. The number you care about in task manager is "commit charge" or "committed" RAM and it is the real amount of memory space that processes would like available. If it is not available in real RAM then it will be satisfied by swap.